# What does d3js.csv.get() do?

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm learning d3js. I came across an example for extracting CSV values [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV). I'm quoting the code:

```
d3.csv("path/to/file.csv")
    .row(function(d) { return {key: d.key, value: +d.value}; })
    .get(function(error, rows) { console.log(rows); });
```

From the description, I get that `.row()` is the accessor here. But the role of the `.get()` is not clear to me. When is this function called, and for what purpose ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.get()` is a function of the underlying AJAX request -- it sends the request and establishes the callback. From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#get):

> xhr.get([callback])
>
> Issues this request using the GET method. If a callback is specified, it will be invoked asynchronously when the request is done or errors; the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the response value.